# How to connect the microphone to Docker app on Windows 10 and save outputs to my local directory?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, docker-toolbox

I cannot connect my docker container to my microphone or local directory on Windows 10 and have been troubleshooting for some time, but I cannot find the issue. I would be truly grateful if anyone could give guidance.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-buster
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
COPY src/ /app
CMD [ "python3", "-u" ,"/app/main.py" ]
```

The error message is "OSError: sndfile library not found".

Comment: If you need to use the host's hardware devices and filesystem, you might find it substantially easier to run the program outside of Docker.  You can use a Python virtual environment to isolate your application's dependencies from the rest of the system.

Comment: I can not get your full idea, please elaborate more. My code should read the microphone and process the output, then save the results to my local directory.

Comment: My python code is doing exactly what it should do outside the docker container.

Comment: ...then you're all set, just run your working code without Docker involved?

Comment: I need docker because my code should run automatically as an application. Also, the docker container should interact with another docker container. This means the output of the first container will be the input of the second one.